# Как оценить время работы алгоритма, зная сложность и значение 'n'?

Tags: алгоритм, сложность, асимптотика

Как оценить примерное время работы алгоритма, зная сложность и значение 'n'?

Например, сложность O(n * log n), а  1 <= n <= 1e5

Использую C++

Comment: Сложность алгоритма и время выполнения - это как скорость и ускорение: зная ускорение, можно оценить прирост скорости в зависимости от времени (в случае с алгоритмом - от размера входных данных), но получить саму скорость невозможно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Оценить - никак.**

Есть алгоритм, например O(n), есть n, условно 5 секунд. Это говорит нам только о том, что приращение длительности между n и n+1 итерациями будет стремиться к 5 секундам. При этом, мы не знаем про базовую длительность, например, она может быть - час. Соответственно, у нас получится час и час+5 секунд.

**Измерить - пожалуйста.**

Записываете время на старте алгоритма, выполняете N циклов, смотрите сколько прошло времени. Делаете еще замеры. Потом интерполируете или экстраполируете значения для вашего N.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 3):

Реальным хронометражом :)

Потому что реальное время - это характеристика не алгоритма, но его конкретной реализации вкупе с конкретным компилятором и конкретным компьютером с конкретной операционной системой...

Comment: не хватает ссылки на ваш таймер)

Comment: @pavel Берем такую книгу - "Оптимизация программ на C++" Гантерота. Там этот вопрос рассмотрен весьма подробно...

Answer (score 2):

сложность O(f(n)) всего лишь означает, что существует K для любого n, такое что O(f(n))<=K*f(n), т.е. сложность алгоритма можно ограничить сверху