# Как найти время выполнения алгоритма с известной сложностью при 100n, зная время выполнения при n?

Tags: алгоритм, теория, сложность

Например, имеем алгоритм со сложностью `O(n*log(2,n))`. При n=10 алгоритм выполняется 5 секунд. Необходимо найти приблизительное время выполнения при n=1000

[Из ответа к схожему вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/685094/293118) получилось найти худшее время:

k*f(n)=time; k*f(10)=5; k = 0.15051

k*f(1000)=**1500**

Есть ли способ найти среднее время выполнения хотя бы с 10-50% ошибкой?

---

Или, например, можно ли сделать оценку по типу

O(100n) < O(100n*log(2,100n)) < 2*O(100n)

500 < O(100n*log(2,100n)) < 1000

Comment: Вот как раз худшее найти невозможно.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/709800/178988

Comment: Почитайте [это](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/«O»_большое_и_«o»_малое). O(n) = O(1000n) = O(10000000n)

Comment: @cppquestions Вы, наверное, имеете ввиду свойство O(f) = O(const*f)?
Но ведь, как уже упомянули ниже, неизвестно в каком виде n в f(n) стоит и можно ли вынести "100" за скобки. А тут меняется не то что функция в 100 раз увеличивается, а значение в этой функции. Просто иначе говоря, если подставить то что вы написали в задачу, мы можем хоть 10^99 значений обрабатывать а время меняться не будет

Comment: Так и есть. Для любой константы C O(C*n) останется O(n)

Comment: Сложность остается та же, но время меняется

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сколь-нибудь точно - вряд ли.

Как минимум, константы зависят еще и от входных данных.

И вообще, вы же не знаете, какое просто `n` в алгоритме идет :) - ну, типа, `an*logn + bn + c` - это тоже `O(n)`. А если у вас при 10 основную роль играет, скажем, `c`?

B экспериментальной физике первое, чему учат начинающих студентов - прямая по двум точкам не строится! (Это не шутка, а непреложный факт.) Вы хотите строить прямую/кривую по единственной точке.

Comment: Хм, ваше сравнение помогло вспомнить что это все и из математики, и имея 100500 значений функцию нельзя восстановить со 100% точностью. 

Однако, если бы это была не О большая а Θ тета, т.е. функции меняются с равной скоростью, то получается можно восстановить по одной точке и сказать само уравнение?

Comment: Ну тета ведь никак не зависит от членов меньшего порядка, так что то, что я писал для O - с чистой совестью можно сказать и для тета. Что можно сказать для O, но не тета - что на деле алгоритм может быть Θ(n), но O(n*log n), и посчитать еще труднее :)

Comment: А еще зависит от того, где именно, при каких n>N, она выходит на указанную O-зависимость - может, оно только после 100500 начинает логарифм проявляться?