# Алгоритм, становящийся лучше

Tags: алгоритм, сложность, асимптотика

[Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/923362/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-100n-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F) вопрос о сложности алгоритмов и можно ли, зная "O" для алгоритма и время для какого-то N, прикинуть время для другого N.

По определению O-обозначений оно начинает асимптотически приближаться после какого-то N. Может, большого.

А может ли теоретически быть так, что при небольших N имеем какую-то "плохую" зависимость (ну, вроде N<sup>2</sup> или вообще N!), которая при больших N переходит в "хорошую" (наподобие N или N*log(N))?

А если может, то нет ли какого-то практического примера? Только не придуманного, а из реальной жизни?

Comment: [которая при больших N переходит в "хорошую"] По определению О от чего-то это асимптотика при БОЛЬШИХ "n".

Comment: И не только теоретически, да и практически так и есть

Comment: if (N < 42) N! else N. Только сложность такого алгоритма всё равно будет O(N!), т.к. она считается для всех входных данных и O(N!) включает O(N). Опять ссылаюсь на [определение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/«O»_большое_и_«o»_малое)

Comment: @cppquestions, нет, сложность такого алгоритмя O(n), поскольку 42! - это константа.

Comment: Что-то с поиском простых чисел было.

Comment: @Qwertiy имелось в виду, если вход меньше какого-то фиксированного значения, то используем алгоритм сложности O(N!), иначе - O(N), а не алгоритмы O(42!) и O(42). Повторяю: O(N!) включает в себя и O(N), и O(1)

Comment: @cppquestions, это утверждение неверно.

Comment: @Qwertiy какое именно? То что O(N!) включает O(N)? Пусть произвольная функция f(N) принадлежит O(N). По определению это означает, что существуют такие k и q, что для любого n > q верно |f(n)| <= k * N. Далее, для любого N > 0 верно, что N <= N!. Значит |f(n)| <= k * N <= k * N!, что по определению означает, что функция f(N) принадлежит O(N!), т.е. множество функций, принадлежащих O(N), принадлежит O(N!). Что неверно?

Comment: @cppquestions, не, стоп. Такими рассуждениями можно сказать, что обычная функция, возвращающая свой аргумент имеет сложность O(n!) поскольку `1 <= k * N!`, но это неверно. Какого-то куска определения не хватает.

Comment: @cppquestions, и я даже знаю, что именно. В программировании через O обозначают то, что в математике обозначается тетой. [Асимптотическая сложность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C#%D0%90%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: @Qwertiy это верно. Я уже дважды приводил определение, но почему-то никто не хочет их читать https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation. Вы, вероятно, путаете О и Θ

Comment: @cppquestions, потому что в программировании именно Θ обозначают через O. Мы вообще-то на сайте программистов, а не математиков. И у вопроса метка [tag:алгоритм], а не [tag:математика].

Comment: @Qwertiy "В программировании через O обозначают то, что в математике обозначается тетой". В приведённой вами ссылке такого нет. Наоборот, там различают О и Θ

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Я старательно избегал применения O при малых N, говоря о "зависимости". Вы посто повторили мою же фразу "По определению O-обозначений оно начинает асимптотически приближаться после какого-то N. Может, большого."

Comment: @Qwertiy Вы впали в то же заблуждение, что и pepsicoca1. Посмотрите выше мой ответ ему. Я не говорю о сложности алгоритма при малых N, а о зависимости времени работы от N при небольших N.

Comment: @Mikhailo, в таких случаях значение при малых n игнорируется, поскольку ограничено константой.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как я понимаю, вас интересует именно так, чтобы при небольших `N` была плохая не столько зависимость, сколько *время* было хуже, чем для больших `N`?

Такое будет вряд ли, так как означает, что при малых `N` используется реально плохой алгоритм - что не имеет смысла, кроме как для создания алгоритма, удовлетворяющего ваше любопытство :)

Но вот такой `O(N^2)`, который по скорости превзойдет при малых `N` `O(N*log N)` - это вроде бы использовалось в стандартной библиотеке C++ в сортировке - при больших `N` была быстрая сортировка, которая, когда массив оказывался почти упорядоченным, переходила на сортировку вставками, которая в этих условиях оказывалась очень быстрой.

*Формально* сортировка вставками `O(N^2)` (хотя при таких условиях - почти отсортированного массива - стремится к `O(N)`).

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*